# The option 'hadoop connectivity' cannot be enabled in this edition of SQL Server

Tags: azure-storage, polybase, sql-server-2022

I'm trying to run polybase in SQL Server 2022.

When running `EXEC sp_configure @configname = 'hadoop connectivity', @configvalue = 7;`

I get the error

> Msg 46934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 177 [Batch Start Line 4]
> The option 'hadoop connectivity' cannot be enabled in this edition of SQL Server.

I'm running this command, as I am trying to enable Azure storage for Polybase. This worked in 2019.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Both Polybase services are running and I can query external SQL Server tables.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using? What does `PRINT @@VERSION;` return?

Comment: @Larnu Great question, forgot to mention this is on developer - 

Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64) 
 Oct  8 2022 05:58:25 
 Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/polybase-connectivity-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#general-remarks): *"Starting in SQL Server 2022 (16.x), Hadoop is no longer supported in PolyBase."*

Comment: Further reading: [Functionality replacement options for Big Data and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-options?view=sql-server-ver16#functionality-replacement-options-for-big-data-and-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is no longer support in Polybase in SQL Server 2022 onwards, this is documented in several locations, such as [PolyBase Connectivity Configuration (Transact-SQL) - General Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/polybase-connectivity-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#general-remarks):

> Starting in SQL Server 2022 (16.x), Hadoop is no longer supported in PolyBase.

And more verbosely [Introducing data virtualization with PolyBase - PolyBase Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#polybase-connectors):

> ## PolyBase connectors
>
> The PolyBase feature provides connectivity to the following external data sources:
>
> | External data sources | SQL Server 2016-2019 with PolyBase | SQL Server 2022 (16.x) with PolyBase | APS PDW | Azure Synapse Analytics |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Oracle, MongoDB, Teradata | Read | Read | No | No |
> | Generic ODBC | Read (Windows Only) | Read (Windows Only) | No | No |
> | Azure Storage | Read/Write | Read/Write | Read/Write | Read/Write |
> | Hadoop | Read/Write | **No** | Read/Write | No |
> | SQL Server | Read | Read | No | No |
> | S3-compatible object storage | No | Read/Write | No | No |
>
> - **SQL Server 2022 (16.x) does not support Hadoop.**
> - SQL Server 2016 (13.x) introduced PolyBase with support for connections to Hadoop and Azure Blob Storage.
> - SQL Server 2019 (15.x) introduced additional connectors, including SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata, and MongoDB.
> - SQL Server 2022 (16.x) introduced the S3-compatible storage connector.

(Both Emphasis mine)

As such, if you are migrating from SQL Server 2019 to SQL Server 2022 and need similar functionality you will need to use a different solution. If this is deal breaking (at least for now) then stay on 2019, as Microsoft *"will continue to support the functionality to the end of life of those products"* for Hadoop.

Unfortunately, I will admit, I don't have familiarity with Hadoop, or PolyBase, however, Microsoft also offer extensive documentation on alternatives in [Big data options on the Microsoft SQL Server platform - Functionality replacement options for Big Data and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-options?view=sql-server-ver16#functionality-replacement-options-for-big-data-and-sql-server).